# Converting complex query to linq with no EXISTS

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Hello everyone can anybody please help me to convert this sql to linq I thnink my biggest problem comes from the not exists statement in sql to linq

```
select count(distinct(GroupID)) from ParticipantModulequestionnaire pmq
inner join ParticipantGroupMember pgm on pmq.participantid = pgm.ParticipantID 
where pmq.moduleid = 46 and  not exists
(select unf.participantid from ParticipantModuleQuestionnaire unf where unf.ParticipantID = pmq.ParticipantID
and unf.ModuleID = 46
and isnull(unf.completedflag,0) <> 0)
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a subquery and check that `Any()` is false. I think this should do it (there will be a couple of minor tweaks necessary to fit it to whatever your context is).

```
var query = 
        from p in ParticipantModulequestionnaire
        join g in ParticipantGroupMember on p.ParticipantId = g.PariticipamtnId
        where p.ModuleId == 46 
         && !ParticipantModuleQuestionnaire.Any(a => 
                        a.ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId
                        && a.ModuleId == 46
                        && (a.CompletedFlag ?? 0) != 0)
        select [p or g, I don't know which].GroupId;
var result = query.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Consider replacing `myEnumerable.Count(...) == 0` with the equivalent `!myEnumerable.Any(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The "not exists" expression is followed by a predicate on "pmq".  See the `Enumerable.Any` and `Enumerable.All` extension methods - you could use either.